# Вывести буквы, которые встречаются только в одном слове. Выполнить операцию над списком множеств сразу

Tags: python, множества

Нужно вывести те буквы, которые встречается только в одном слове.

```
s = 'Привет, клак у Аллы дела'
st = set()
s = s.lower()
s = s.split()
ls = []
for i in s:
    a = "".join(c for c in i if c.isalpha()) # оставляю в строке только буквы
    ls.append(set(a))
m = set()
for i in ls:
    m ^= i # симметричная разность множеств
print(m, len(m))
```

из - за того что я выполняю операцию последовательно, то ответ неверный.
{'л', 'и', 'д', 'п', 'у', 'в', 'к', 'т', 'р', 'а', 'ы'} 11
например, буква А не должна выводиться, т.к. оно есть в трех словах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

можно сделать в лоб:

```
text = 'Привет клак у Аллы дела'
words = text.lower().split()

res = []
for w in words:
    for l in w:
        if text.count(l) == w.count(l):
            res.append(l)

print(res)
```

**вариант 2:**

ну или для любителей одной строки:

```
res = [l for w in words for l in w if text.count(l) == w.count(l)]
```

**вариант 3:**

через множества поизвратнее:

```
text = 'Привет клак у Аллы дела'
words = list(map(set, text.lower().split()))

res = set()

for i in range(len(words)):
    res |= words[i].difference(*set.union(*[words[j] for j in range(len(words)) if i != j]))

print(res)
```

**вариант 4:**

и однострочный вариант:

```
res = set.union(*[words[i].difference(*set.union(*[words[j] for j in range(len(words)) if i != j])) for i in range(len(words))])
```

Comment: а через множества никак?

Comment: можно и через множества, сейчас код причешу

Comment: снизу прикрепил еще свою реализацию, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: мап пока нельзя использовать ;c

Comment: ничего не мешает `map` превратить в `[set(w) for w in text.split()]` - в общем то какая разница?

Comment: понял))) спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

вот так не бред?

```
str = 'Привет, клак у Аллы дела'
st = set()
str = str.lower()
s = str.split()

ls = []
for i in s:
    a = "".join(c for c in i if c.isalpha())
    for j in a:
        st.add(j)

b = set([l for w in s for l in w if str.count(l) > w.count(l)])


print(st - b)
```